# Convert JSON in print format to valid JSON

Tags: php, file, input, json

I have a text file that is formatted like JSON, but in a print/view friendly format and I want to convert that string to valid JSON.
Basically, I want to read the file using **PHP5** and call **json_decode** to deserialize the string.
But, json_decode is not able to parse the "print-friendly" json string.

I am getting error 4 Invalid or malformed JSON.

It looks like someone else had a similar issue as me: [PHP json_decode() returns NULL with valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json)

I am using notepad++ to write the json file.

So, how can I convert

**FROM:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "thumbImg": "thumbImg",
            "street": "street",
            "city": "Fort Worth",
            "state": "Texas",
            "zip": "76192-0001",
            "url": "url"
        }
    ]
}
```

**TO:**

```
{"data":[{"thumbImg": "thumbImg", "street": "street", "city": "Fort Worth", "state": "Texas", "zip": "76192-0001", "url": "url"}]
```

I even tried doing the following:

```
<?php
$filename = "links.json";
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
    
$lines = file($filename);
    
$data = "";
;
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $formatted = trim($line);
    $formatted = str_replace("\r", "", $formatted);
    $formatted = str_replace("\n", "", $formatted);
    $data .= $formatted;        
}

$json = json_decode($data, true);
?>
```

I did a var_dump of the resulting json string and http://jsonlint.com/ marked it as valid json; however, json_decode is not able to deserialize the json string for some reason.

Thank you!

**SOLUTION**
I set the encoding of the text file to UTF-8 without BOM and it works fine now. thank you all!

Comment: The data parses with no problems for me.

Comment: It works when I read from a text file (without mucking about with reformatting the text). It sounds like you have started with "I'm having problems reading a file" but you ended up asking "How can I reformat this file?", which is several steps down the line from the actual problem and has resulted in a question that isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: `json_decode` works perfectly for me: http://codepad.org/wcNFa2F5  You should try `file_get_contents` to read the file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Have you tried `file_get_contents()` instead? Also when you read using `file()` there is no need to call `fopen()`.

Comment: Ah, the byte-order mark must have been the cause of the parsing error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$filename = "links.json";
$file = file_get_contents($filename);    

$json = json_decode($file, true);
?>
```

References:
 - **[`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**
 - **[`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**

Comment: Thank you. It turns out the file-encoding of my text file was off. I changed the encoding of the source file to UTF-8 without BOM and it works great now! thank you all for the great support!