# Extracting specific key value from JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following response from a payment gateway (JSON):

```
    {
  "response": {
    "token": "ch_lfUYEBK14zotCTykezJkfg",
    "success": true,
    "amount": 400,
    "currency": null,
    "description": "test charge",
    "email": "user@user.com",
    "ip_address": "203.192.1.172",
    "created_at": "2012-06-20T03:10:49Z",
    "status_message": "Success!",
    "error_message": null,
    "card": {
      "token": "card_nytGw7koRg23EEp9NTmz9w",
      "display_number": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0000",
      "scheme": "master",
      "address_line1": "42 Sevenoaks St",
      "address_line2": null,
      "address_city": "Lathlain",
      "address_postcode": "6454",
      "address_state": "WA",
      "address_country": "Australia"
    },
    "transfer": null
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the `success => true` part in an if statement like so:

```
<?php
    if($response['success'] == true) {
     // continue transaction
    }
?>
```

Without any luck, so I'm asking for some help on how I achieve this. It would be useful to be able to extract other key values too.

Thanks

Comment: there is a function like `json_decode`

Comment: In case of PHP code why don't you just decode your json & try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you aren't able to `json_decode($response)` is because `$response` is an object, not a JSON string.

The Pin-PHP library will automatically decode all requests for you, as per https://github.com/noetix/pin-php/blob/master/src/Pin/Handler.php#L87

To see if the response has been successful, use the **response object** as an object:

```
if ($response->response->success) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "Failed :(";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Your `$response` is already an object, therefore this expression should work:

```
if ($response->response->success == true) {
    // etc
}
```

Are you just looking for code that decodes the string representation? If so:

```
$response = <<<'EOM'
{
  "response": {
    "token": "ch_lfUYEBK14zotCTykezJkfg",
    "success": true,
    "amount": 400,
    "currency": null,
    "description": "test charge",
    "email": "user@user.com",
    "ip_address": "203.192.1.172",
    "created_at": "2012-06-20T03:10:49Z",
    "status_message": "Success!",
    "error_message": null,
    "card": {
      "token": "card_nytGw7koRg23EEp9NTmz9w",
      "display_number": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0000",
      "scheme": "master",
      "address_line1": "42 Sevenoaks St",
      "address_line2": null,
      "address_city": "Lathlain",
      "address_postcode": "6454",
      "address_state": "WA",
      "address_country": "Australia"
    },
    "transfer": null
  }
}
EOM;

$responseData = json_decode($responseText, true);

if ($responseData['response']['success'] == true) {
 // continue transaction
}
```

Comment: There's one more `"response"` key in there.

Comment: This returns null, I did try this before hand. Code: http://codepad.org/BmAT3bMY

$responseData = NULL but $response does have the JSON array.

Comment: I have also tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json with no success. Any tips?

Comment: @Dean Updated answer with code that definitely works.

Comment: @Jack thanks, but I am getting the `$response` from a payment gateway https://pin.net.au/docs/api/charges#post-charges So I can't really edit the response I get from them. How would you suggest I proceed?

Comment: @Dean Then, the response is possibly empty and you should check the response headers.

Comment: Perhaps I should say, it returns `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`.

Comment: @Dean Then the response is already a proper object, so `$response->response->success` should be `true`.

Comment: Spot on you are. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a json object like:

```
$jsonobject = json_encode($responseText);
$response = $jsonobject->response->success;
if($response === true) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Same deal as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565067/extracting-specific-key-value-from-json-array-in-php#comment22061209_15565109 it returns null.