# json_decode returns NULL despite apparently correct JSON response

Tags: php, json

I am trying to interpret the response from a web service call using json_decode. The JSON appears to be valid (have checked in online validators and such) but json_decode still returns NULL.

The data returned by the web service is as follows:

```
[{"id":"cc9dfabc36abc54c5a7","extension":"001","links":{"self":"https:\/\/someurl\/api\/response\/@me\/001\/cc9dfabc36abc54c5a7"}}]
```

The web service response data is stored in `$result`. My code to decode the JSON is as follows:

```
if (is_null(json_decode($result))){
        $callObj = json_decode($result, true);  
        $callID = $callObj->extension;  
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<BR>Could not decode response <BR>";
        $callID = 'error';
    }           
    return $callID;
```

Comment: Check this out. Seems to be the same problem as yours
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json

Comment: Hi, yes I saw that but thought the problem must be different, my output is coming straight from a web service. How could I test for illegal characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the first test be negative (!is_null)? Only if it isn't null (and therefore a json object) should you then proceed.

Also, the second json_encode function you're passing a 'true' as the second argument which makes the returned object an associative array rather than an object.

The below alterations appeared to work for me.

```
if (!is_null(json_decode($result))){
    $callObj = json_decode($result, true);
    $callID = $callObj[0]['extension'];
}
else
{
    echo "<BR>Could not decode response <BR>";
    $callID = 'error';
}
return $callID;
```

Comment: Argh! The shame. Yes you are right on both counts. The 'true' argument was part of my testing, but the !is_null was a complete oversight, couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks :)