# JSON URL Requests Returns Null Even Though json_last_error returns 0

Tags: php, json

So, I'm using file_get_contents(url) to return some JSON data.
When I use `var_dump(json_decode($result, true));` it always returns `NULL`

I used `echo json_last_error();` and that returns 0, indicating no error.

I've spent ages trying to find a solution to my problem.
(Also this is the first time I've ever used JSON)

What could possibly be wrong here?

Here is the value of result when I just request 1 item (It's long, so I'm just gonna show 1)

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Id": 1034,
      "Name": "Direzza DZ102",
      "TyreBrand": {
      "Id": 10,
      "Name": "Dunlop"
    },
      "ShortDescription": "An aggressively styled sports performance tyre that is guaranteed to deliver. With features such as advanced handling in wet and dry conditions, Hydrogrip braking technologies, reduced fuel consumption and noise reduction. The Direzza DZ102 is the sports performance tyre that won't     disappoint.",
      "Images": [
        {
          "Id": "0b2773b6-eb10-4eea-bd69-3061cf4e6778",
          "Url": "https://vlogicmedia1.blob.core.windows.net/tyre-images/19/0b2773b6-eb10-4eea-bd69-3061cf4e6778.png",
          "Type": "Manf Angle Large",
          "Caption": ""
        },
        {
          "Id": "ac474cc2-30ce-43df-9856-d0a1ad722acd",
          "Url": "https://vlogicmedia1.blob.core.windows.net/tyre-images/18/ac474cc2-30ce-43df-9856-d0a1ad722acd.png",
          "Type": "Manf Angle Main",
          "Caption": null
        },
        {
          "Id": "1a386318-a4ee-4c5e-a808-e9b3031eeb82",
          "Url": "https://vlogicmedia1.blob.core.windows.net/tyre-    images/17/1a386318-a4ee-4c5e-a808-e9b3031eeb82.png",
          "Type": "Manf Angle Thumb",
          "Caption": null
        }
      ],
      "PerformanceCategory": "Ultra High Performance"
    }
  ],
  "Page": 1,
  "PerPage": 1,
  "Total": 40
}
```

Comment: Is the value of `$result` also in json format?

Comment: Can you show your `$result` ?

Comment: Possible character encoding issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call

Comment: This :  _that won`'t`     disappoint._  in `"ShortDescription":` is escaping your json.

Comment: Ah, yes, that could be it. How can I fix that without editing the JSON itself? (I don't have access to it)

Comment: @Zoron19 maybe `utf8_decode()`

Comment: @Alex That doesn't seem to help ):

Comment: @Zoron19 can you please provide how do you gather data in json ?

Comment: @Alex I have access to an API that returns JSON data from URL requests. It generates a URL to fetch the data I need, then I use that URL in `file_get_contents(url)`

Comment: @Zoron19 so have you tried `$contents = utf8_encode($contents);` than `$results = json_decode($contents);`  ?

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I tried that. Didn't seem to do anything.