# Access Json Object PHP (String Not Array)

Tags: php, json

Yes, I have read previous questions and I know how to access a JSON object and how to convert it into an array. I know about json_encode/decode. My problem is that my JSON response has a string, arrays and all and it will always return NULL when I access the data directly.

```
  object(Unirest\Response)#8 (4) {
    ["code"]=>
      int(200)
    ["body"]=>
      string(666) "{ "ticker": "AAPL:US", ".."
    ["headers"]=>
    array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
```

Normally you would be able to directly access the object like this and this worked just fine when I last accessed the script a few days ago:

```
$response->body->ticker
```

Or you could use json_decode with true to turn it into an array.

```
$array = json_decode($response->body, true);
```

However, all of this no longer works. I believe they changed something with the output because it was working just a while ago but I have no clue. Any idea how to access the ticker data? I tested it with a different API and the same commands are working just fine to retrieve data from a different API, but the output seems to be different.

Comment: What is the output of [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)? What is the complete string being parsed?

Comment: that's not json. that's a var_dump of a PHP object, which contains somewher a json **STRING**. you cannot access that string's components as an object until AFTER it's been decoded.

Answer (score 0):

`$response->body` is a json string *assuming you didnt shorten it so much as to loose someting important* and therefore needs to be seperately converted to a PHP data item.

As its a json string representing an object why not convert it to a PHP object like so

```
$body = json_decode($response->body);
```

Then you can address its properties like

```
$body->ticker
```

Alternatively

```
$response->body = json_decode($response->body);
```

Now you can address it as you expected i.e.

```
$response->body->ticker
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already tried that. First thing I tried. I am getting Trying to get property of non-object when I use it like that.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the JSON formatting, else this would work, but doesnt seem like I will find it, tried it for hours, every variation

Comment: In that case post a complete json string and not just a piece of it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally solved it after reading this answer: 
[PHP json_decode() returns NULL with valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json)

Apparently, as I assumed earlier it was a formatting issue. I did not know that JSON would return NULL if the object includes non-UTF8 code and/or BOM codes.

I couldn't find any BOM codes but I suppose there was some non-UTF8 that was breaking it.

Long story short this works:

```
$dec =  json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $response->body), true );         
 echo $dec['ticker'];
```

Well at least I now know a lot more about JSON which will come in handy some day ;)