# What is the correct JSON format.?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON encode format like this but when i decode i got null. Can anyone help me?

```
[{"system":"ecode","servicetype":"eservice","service_name_type":"eCode","show_service":"eCode","id"
:"32211","amount":"50.0000","bank":"BBL","bank_ref":"000011539775","method":"debit","transaction_ref"
:"150032211","create_date":"2015-07-21 09:46:18","customer_id":"17111","name":"\u0e2a\u0e21\u0e2b\u0e24
\u0e17\u0e31\u0e22 \u0e04\u0e13\u0e32\u0e1b\u0e23\u0e32\u0e0a\u0e0d\u0e4c","address":"19 \u0e17\u0e14
\u0e2a\u0e2d\u0e1a \u0e41\u0e02\u0e27\u0e07\u0e17\u0e38\u0e48\u0e07\u0e2a\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e2b\u0e49\u0e2d
\u0e07 \u0e40\u0e02\u0e15\u0e2b\u0e25\u0e31\u0e01\u0e2a\u0e35\u0e48","pv":"\u0e01\u0e23\u0e38\u0e07\u0e40
\u0e17\u0e1e\u0e21\u0e2b\u0e32\u0e19\u0e04\u0e23","zip":"10210","email":"somtoo@tot.co.th"}]
```

Comment: The JSON you posted is valid. You are probably doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: please share your effort

Comment: this json is valid . . you can check it here [jsonparser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: If you decide to split the string into separate lines inside  the qoute marks then ensure that line breaks are at the end of a 'value pair'. It will then decode correctly. [demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/private/19c227b6d62d80)

Comment: what is output when you use var_dump($yourjsonobject);

Answer (score 0):

It could be the encoding of the special characters. You could ask json_last_error() to get definite information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json 
Did you check this question?