# JSON not decoding in php

Tags: php, json

i am using json decoding function in php to decode this

```
{"department_id":"3123a79d-9e33-543f-c9be-4cc7ff79982c",
"ug_id":"217a783c-7970-8d92-6c99-5225a3ec533a",
"pg_id":"90da4eb5-6b75-44b0-2ce0-5226c8f60f8e",
"staff_id":"1e6364a3-0b3d-6384-a6c2-5225bd41c7fd",
"from_date":"date_start",
"to_date":"date_end"}
```

I have use `json_decode($str)` and `json_decode($str,true)` both, but i am getting `null` output. Please help me if possible.
Here is my complete code

```
$query='SELECT params FROM userreports WHERE id=\''.$_REQUEST['record'].'\'';
            $query_exe=$db->query($query);
            $res=$db->fetchByAssoc($query_exe);

                $json=$res['params'];
                $arr=json_decode($json,true);
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($arr) ;exit;
```

Comment: it's `json_decode($str , true)` not ` json_deocde($str,true)`.. It's A valid json .. povide some more code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json please check this one. Use json_last_error() to get definite information.

Comment: i am getting output as 4

Comment: Works absolutely fine https://eval.in/486176

Comment: Should work if you do it like this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cdc849114fee78947abeada208c62f2f09c45314

Comment: Some more code please... :)

Comment: 4 Means Syntax Error

Comment: Please check my complete code

Comment: what Mihriban Minaz wrote + are you sure you get the right values out of the DB? try a `print_r($res)`, too

Comment: This code is also very sensitive for SQL Injection because you're getting a parameter directly from the request. Make sure you escape this parameter. Take a look at MySQLi with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code it is working fine:

```
<?php
$str = '{"department_id":"3123a79d-9e33-543f-c9be-4cc7ff79982c",
"ug_id":"217a783c-7970-8d92-6c99-5225a3ec533a",
"pg_id":"90da4eb5-6b75-44b0-2ce0-5226c8f60f8e",
"staff_id":"1e6364a3-0b3d-6384-a6c2-5225bd41c7fd",
"from_date":"date_start",
"to_date":"date_end"}';

$arrStr = json_decode($str);

print_r($arrStr);

?>
```