# JSON decode returns NULL

Tags: php, json

I'm receiving a JSON response from a url which on decoding returns null while decoding it directly from the string it produces gives results.

String returned from the url:

```
{"status_code":0,"response":{"names":"Bon Charles"},"status_message":"Succeeded."}
```

Result from URL on decoding: NULL
Result on taking the produced string and hard-coding it into a string:

```
object(stdClass)#19 (3) { ["status_code"]=> int(0) ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#20 (1) { ["names"]=> string(15) "Bon Charles" } ["status_message"]=> string(16) "Succeeded." }
```

Below is the function that calls the url for the response:

```
public function checkLoginStatus() {
        $status = $this->postLoginsJSON();

        $values = json_decode($status);
        $json_string = '{"status_code":0,"response":{"names":"Bon Charles"},"status_message":"Login Succeeded."}';
        $a = json_decode($json_string);
        var_dump($values);//returns null
        var_dump($a);//returns values
    }
```

Kindly assist.

Comment: Can't help much as you haven't said what `$this->postLoginsJSON()` does. The result of `$status` could be an object, an array, or anything. You could try converting it to a string.

Comment: please print the output of `var_dump($this->postLoginsJSON());` - most probably it does not generate valid JSON for some reason.

Comment: "It could be the encoding of the special characters. You could ask json_last_error() to get definite information."
From http://stackoverflow.com/a/2410358/452708

Comment: Have you checked the returned JSON string at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com). At least you will know that it is valid and that the `json_decode` parameters will need to be `tweaked` (technical term ;-/).

Comment: Hello, $this->postLoginsJSON() returns the below result:{
status_code: 0,
response: {
names: "Bon Charles"
},
status_message: "Succeeded."
}