# json_decode fails to read text file with data stored in json format

Tags: php, html, json, r

The following output is what generated when I save a R- data frame into Json format. My dataframe has mix of html links and some accent characters. I have to work with this file in PHP/Html environment.

```
library(jsonlite)
output_json <- toJSON(output, dataframe = "rows", pretty = T)
write(output_json, file = "output.txt")

  {
  "PMID":"<a href= \"http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=19369233\"
           target=\"_blank\">19369233</a>",
  "Title":"Delayed achievement of cytogenetic and molecular response is
          associated with increased risk of progression among patients with
          chronic myeloid leukemia in early chronic phase receiving
          high-dose or standard-dose imatinib therapy.",
  "Author":"Quintás-Cardama A",
  "Random  author names":"Järås M", "Imrédi E", "Tímár J."      
},
```

When I open the `output.txt` file or print output on html page the accent letters in first author and last author changes to `?` eg: `Imr�di E`.

When I use below PHP code decode to read the json file it fails and returns NULL. On  research at SO I am certain that the issue is from the accent characters, and also in some cases improper escaping of the new lines `\r\n` or html tags.

```
!-- language: lang-php --> 
$r_output = file_get_contents('output.txt');
$array_json = json_decode($r_output, true);
```

I tried to fix by following suggestions Eg:  [How do I handle newlines in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json) or [PHP json_decode() returns NULL with valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json) etc. However, could not solve this issue.

Hence, tagging PHP and R users, to find out if there is a better way to write the JSON format in R to avoid this issue or clean the json format before reading it in php ?

Thank you for help

Comment: The issue is probably caused by a charset mismatch. I'd wager that the input data is ISO-8859 and JSON is inherently assumed to be UTF8.

Comment: sounds like it worked fine, your just not matching the page encoding

Comment: @sammitch you are probably right. @miken32, I thought by default `tojson` encodes in UTF-8 format.  Thank you for pointing that  encoding is required when write function is called, thank you for the link. I hope it is not duplicate. I should have probably thought to solve the encoding issue from write file aspect, rather than trying to address the conversion in tojson() function. Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to `utf8_encode` the `$r_output` and remove the line breaks i.e.:

```
$r_output = utf8_encode(file_get_contents('output.txt'));
$r_output = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$r_output);
$array_json = json_decode($r_output, true);
```

alternatively try `utf8_decode`:

```
$r_output = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('output.txt'));
$r_output = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$r_output);
$array_json = json_decode($r_output, true);
```

---

PS: your json seems invalid ->`"Imrédi E", Tímár J."`

Comment: I fixed the json format. Thank you for noting it.

Answer (score 1):

Write the [output file as UTF-8](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html) to begin with:

```
library(jsonlite)
output_json <- toJSON(output, dataframe = "rows", pretty = T)
con<-file("output.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
write(output_json, file = con)
```