# how to json decode in php facebook data

Tags: php

```
{"userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","facebookImages":["https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/s130x130\/23754671_1686349868084129_7668071878508814431_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=4ed3575fb34c2898622ca8f5e9e61d87&oe=5B5334BE","https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/s130x130\/23755759_1686340854751697_6411654600438255320_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=cd5cad9e750bd5b2b3643e35e9378492&oe=5B4F87B4","https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/19430015_1540297619356022_2870621101585404416_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=c6bede9dfad60d083e1f8247b4f75251&oe=5B972540","https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/s130x130\/17264338_1425411314177987_7613224491150241933_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=06171b397fed8bf7d700c362232408c0&oe=5B4EAC34","https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/s130x130\/15727089_1349018085150644_8503578420186716749_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=7301a4bff306485830752e5d7a2f5fb1&oe=5B862CCC","https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/15193442_1306086582777128_8952457517992921711_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=c25fc35269ecc708bbc1e977d49652cc&oe=5B8A3631","https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/15094299_1298839946835125_1034443644592328815_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=bc6f72e37a53df46ced3aaa453d99572&oe=5B8A6AC0","https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/15085724_1298837180168735_5400755773976044623_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=9fc318ef487aadf07b065cb2d05ca27f&oe=5B928BC7","https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/p130x130\/15073363_1297910186928101_3761837961428672932_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=93716a0c613bd614cb8eb37a378811e9&oe=5B5C5406"]}
```

Comment: So, what did you try? [ask]

Comment: i am trying with json_decode but it given null

Comment: that should be in your question ...

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json

Comment: You have way too little code here showing what you have tried. We cannot read your mind or guess what you have done to get that string in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json_decode();

```
<?php
$decoded_array = json_decode($data, true);
$decoded_object = json_decode($data);
```

Where `$data` is your json string.

Comment: i am trying same but its unable to decode it, given NULL

Comment: can you add your code at least.

Comment: works for me: https://3v4l.org/EuC2G