# post JSON object to PHP

Tags: php, json

so i have a gigantic javascript object that i want to pass it on to PHP.

What i'm trying is:
   - use stringify to put it as the value of a hidden field
   - hit submit

In PHP, if I

```
echo $_POST['hidden']
```

the JSON string seems perfect,
but when i use

```
json_decode($_POST['hidden'])
```

i get NULL

If i use jQuery's

```
$.post
```

, i get exactly the desired result: i am able to use json_decode on it.

Can someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-php

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON string might contain some extra slashes.
Try `strip_slashes` before `json_decode`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to do urldecode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

here is same error types

```
//wrong
$str1 = <<<EOD
{“dealList”:”\r\n\t”}
EOD;

//right
$str2 = <<<EOD
{“dealList”:”\\r\\n\\t”}
EOD;

//wrong
$str3 = <<<EOD
{‘dealList’:'\r\n’}
EOD;

//wrong
$str4 = <<<EOD
{‘dealList’:'\\r\\n’}
EOD;

//wrong
$str5 = “{‘dealList’:'\r\n’}”;

//wrong
$str6 = “{‘dealList’:'\\r\\n’}”;

//right
$str7 = ‘{“dealList”:”\r\n”}’;

$c = json_decode($str1);
```

Comment: ok, that seems reasonable. but if i'm using (JSON2.js)JSON.stringify(object) on the javascript side, i post that string through a hidden form field, how can i control it so i can get the correct string?