# How to POST JSON in body for functional tests in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I'm writing some functional tests for a POST API endpoint. I've reviewed the documentation and can't find a way to add content to the POST body. The post method for sfBrowser:

```
post('some url',array('x'=>'y'))
```

Only creates POST parameters (in this case x=y). Is there anyway of adding content to the post body using sfBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?121353-Send-JSON-object-to-PHP), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211943/post-json-object-to-php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), the POST format takes parameter:value format, so you can send your JSON with some code like:

```
post('some url', array('json_data' => json_encode($toJson))
```

and then decode in your action with

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($request->getParameter('json_data'));
```

but you need to associate your JSON data with a parameter name in your POST to retrieve it on the server side.

As a side note, after looking at the Symfony code, the parameters are given straight to $_POST except for CSRF, which is tweaked.

Comment: I have no trouble with decoding values passed in the POST parameter format. The problem is adding data to the body of a POST. I'm using Zapier and they send data as a POST body and not as a POST parameter.  The key here is sending POST body via the sfBrowser POST method. Having looked at the underlying code I don't think it is at all possilbe without changing the sfBrowser code which is a bit beyond me at the moment.