# PHP not converting JSON using 'json_decode()'

Tags: php, json

I have a very simple bit of code

```
$pc1 = $_POST['post_code1'];
$pc2 = $_POST['post_code2'];
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:".$pc1."%20to:".$pc2;
$url_data = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($url_data);
var_dump($json_data);
```

`$url_data` is full of juicy json stuff but `$json_data` returns `NULL`. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Are you sure it's full of purely valid JSON?

Comment: Does the URL pass validation? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: How deep is it? PHP doc: "NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit." The recursion limit is 512 by default.

Comment: `var_dump($url_data)`? Maybe [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is disabled?

Comment: no I got my provider to enable `fopen()` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following worked after find a number of people with similar problems

```
$json_data = json_decode(utf8_encode($url_data),true);
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689195/563247)

Comment: This is correct, because `file_get_contents` does so byte-for-byte and not character-for-character.