# Trying to count the length of an array from JSON list

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to count the length of an array that I converted from JSON using `json_decode` in php but it is not working for some reason. This is my current code. The JSON list contains an array that has 10,000 items. I am pretty sure that I am missing something. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PHP

```
<?php
$fl = file_get_contents($somepath);
$text = json_decode($fl, true);

$len = count($text["alphalist"]);

echo $len;
?>
```

JSON

```
{
"alphalist": [{
        "a": "alphabet1."
    }, {
        "b": "alphabet2."
    }, {
        "c": "alphabet3."
    }, {
        "d": "alphabet4."
    }, {
        "e": "alphabet5."
    }
    ....
    {
        "zzzzz": "alphabet10000."
    }
]
}
```

Comment: What does `echo $len;` returns so far?

Comment: it returns `0` when I tested it

Comment: I have just tested your code and `json_decoding` your `JSON` string returns 5 elements in the array. Are you sure you are posting the full code?

Comment: Sorry. You are right. That is not the full code. The entire json file has 20000 lines. I validated it with online verifiers but I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: What does `var_dump($text["alphalist"]);` returns?

Comment: It returns `null`, but the json list is clearly still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79239/discussion-between-blank-kuma-and-d4v1d).

Comment: I believe the first thing that you should be verifying is not echo $len,  rather what is in $text.

Comment: Please post the solution to your problem so it can help others and accept the answer within two days :)

Comment: Yea that is what I am doing right now actually.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was actually here in response to another similar question.

[PHP not converting JSON using 'json_decode()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319062/php-not-converting-json-using-json-decode)

So after some testing with user D4V1D, it turns out that the problem was due to the PHP function `json_decode` not working because it wasn't in the UTF-8 format. The workaround for this is

```
$fl = file_get_contents($somepath);
$text = json_decode(utf8_encode($fl), true);
$len = count($text["alphalist"]);
```

Now `$len` will give the correct array length. If there is any error or improvement to be made in my explanation, just place it in the comments and I will correct it accordingly.