# json decode $_POST parameter php

Tags: php, json

I try to decode a string with `json_decode()` function.

```
$in = $_POST['json'];
$jsonIn = json_decode($in);
```

for example

```
$in = '{"company":"q","address":"q","phone":"q","mobile":"q","email":"q"}';
```

if I try to force the raw string, it works fine, but if I use $in instead, it doesn't

the proof that it does / doesn't is the fact that if I try to access for example

```
$jsonIn->company
```

in the first case it returns me `null`, in the second one it returns me `"q"`.

anybody can explain?
thanks in advance
Dario

Comment: How do you get JSON in the post?

Comment: can you show `var_dump($_POST['json'])`

Comment: $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'url.php',data: {json : JSON.stringify(json2Send)},

Comment: From what I read here it's the magic_quotes thingy: http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2008/11/json_decode_php/

Comment: @TimVermaelen yeah, I was just about to suggest that. Especially likely if you're runnig on PHP 5.2, since it's on by default then.  If you've got control of the server I suggest disabling magic quotes, they're evil http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'{&quot;company&quot;:&quot;q&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;q&quot;,&quot;phone&quot;:&quot;q&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;:&quot;q&quot;}'</font> <i>(length=140)</i>
</pre>

Comment: possible duplicate of [json_decode returns NULL (php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-php), specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/2197308/8331

Comment: I have disabled magic quotes and the other json_decode that contains an array is giving me an error. {"items":["final product"]} if I check $jsonIn->items[0]=='final product' it returns me false. but if I echo $jsonIn->items[0] it gives me "final product". here is the <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'final product'</font> <i>(length=15)</i>
</pre>

Comment: just added json_decode($in,true) and it worked fine

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo, create an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: @Dario Rusignuolo: you still didn't answer - why do you have JSON in POST? Who sends it?

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo can you show the data from a print_r wrapped in pre `<?php echo "<pre>";print_r(json_decode($_POST['json']));echo "</pre>"; ?>`

Comment: Jeffrey: done. zerkms: sent from javascript. I simplyfied the json, but it's a little more complx 'cause there are some arrays in it. Killrawr: you want me to post what u want even if the problem was solved?

Comment: @Killrawr I modified the code, so I can't restore my php file at that situation

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo if the problem has already been solved then, don't worry about it. :) regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved after disabling the `Magic Quotes`.