# How can a javascript object be passed to PHP and values accessed

Tags: php, jquery, object, post, json

I need to pass a javascript object to PHP then decode it as an associative array.  I have read many similar questions on this site and googled for a few hrs now.  My problem is that I cannot find a SIMPLE example that covers both sides (javascript and PHP).  Here is a simplified version of what im trying to do.  Posting data as a key/value pair is the only way I can get anything to pass.  There is a DIV in the HTML that is used to display the answer.  All I want to do is confirm that the data gets past in this code.

All I get is "POST array is loaded with", which to me suggests that the POST array contains data, but im either decoding it wrong or accessing the associative array incorrectly. I have also read the AJAX and POST pages on the JQUERY site but the examples don't get me where I need to be.  If I assign strob a simple string value it gets passed perfectly.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var obj={};
            obj.value1="foo";
            obj.value2="bar";
            var strob=JSON.stringify(obj);
            $.post("byterecord.php",{sendToValue: strob},
            function(data){
                $('#display').html(data.returnFromValue);
            }, 
            "json");
        });
```

byterecord.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sendToValue'])){

$aarray=json_decode($_POST['sendToValue'],true);
$strval=$aarray[value1];

}else{
$strval = "nothing.";
}

echo json_encode(array("returnFromValue"=>"POST array is loaded with " .$strval));  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the object directly:

```
$.post("byterecord.php", obj, function() {});
```

Then in php, you could get it by:

```
$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2'];
```

Comment: Nope, there must be something fundamentally wrong with my brain or site.  Now I get nothing passed.  Here are the URLs: http://learningbyte.comze.com/indexexample.html and byterecord.php

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. There's an extra ',' at the end, line 29, after }). put a ; instead

Comment: Good catch but no function still.  I'm REALLY thankful for the help its driving me crazy.  I don't mind starting from scratch with fresh code that passes any object from JQuery to PHP then sends back some notification that the data made it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine:

However, your request, when examined from the console, is generating PHP notice :

```
  Notice: Use of undefined constant value1 - assumed 'value1'
```

Either change the param from

```
 $aarray[value1];
```

to

```
 $aarray['value1'];
```

Or, try with turning off the error_reporting :

```
 error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: I am always impressed that smart people are willing to help newbies like me.  In that regard, I have to admit that i'm still not getting this to work.  I redid the two files so they look like the code above, except that I now reference $aarray['value1'] as suggested above.  When I use firebug in chrome all seems to be correct (except I dont understand: sendToValue=%7B%22value1%22%3A%22foo%22%2C%22value2%22%3A%22bar%22%7D) To me this means that there is some value in the $_POST array corresponding to sendToValue but that the code to I use to access the value of 'value1' is not correct.

Comment: Im not sure why, but a stripslashes suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2197308/1024783 solved the problem.  Thanks Pablo!