# Parsing json data in php

Tags: php, json

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. I am getting json data into my php script in the following format:

![json structure][1]

I want to loop through "OnlinePlayers"... which, from reading other questions here, seems to be at

```
$json->{'ServerStatus'}->{'OnlinePlayers'};
```

assuming I decode it into an object and not an array, as

```
$json = json_decode($_POST["jsonData"]);
```

I have tried var_dump() to get the results out of that... I have tried adding "true" to the decode to get an array and then var_dump() on that - I can't get the result! I know it's there because if I just print out the raw $_POST["jsonData"], I see it there.

It's terribly formatted and I'm sorry for the eyesore, only including it here to show the data IS there. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I just want each "Name" inside of "OnlinePlayers" (inside of "ServerStatus").

```
{
    "Plugins": [
        {
            "Name": "GroupManager v2.0 (Dev2.13.14) (Phoenix)"
        },
        {
            "Name": "WorldEdit v5.5.8"
        },
        {
            "Name": "BukkitCompat vR22A"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Websend v2.5.1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Vault v1.2.27-b349"
        },
        {
            "Name": "dynmap v1.9.1-869"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Essentials vDev2.13.14"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Citizens v2.0.11-SNAPSHOT (build 1026)"
        },
        {
            "Name": "EssentialsProtect vDev2.13.14"
        },
        {
            "Name": "EssentialsSpawn vDev2.13.14"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Sentry v1.7.1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "EssentialsGeoIP vDev2.13.14"
        },
        {
            "Name": "EssentialsChat vDev2.13.14"
        },
        {
            "Name": "EssentialsAntiBuild vDev2.13.14"
        }
    ],
    "Invoker": {
        "XP": 0.4446353614330292,
        "IP": "/81.31.95.254:63218",
        "FoodLevel": 17,
        "CurrentItemIndex": 4,
        "Location": {
            "World": "Runic Paradise",
            "Yaw": 60.18408203125,
            "Y": 122.45612876403841,
            "X": 6645.424098440775,
            "Pitch": 28.879852294921875,
            "Z": -23.14999955097173
        },
        "XPLevel": 526,
        "Health": 19,
        "Inventory": [
            {
                "Durability": 0,
                "Amount": 64,
                "Type": 89,
                "Slot": 0
            },
            {
                "Durability": 0,
                "Amount": 2,
                "Type": 363,
                "Slot": 1
            },
            {
                "Data": 11,
                "Durability": 11,
                "Amount": 1,
                "Type": 35,
                "Slot": 2
            },
            {
                "Data": 14,
                "Durability": 14,
                "Amount": 1,
                "Type": 35,
                "Slot": 3
            },
            {
                "Durability": 0,
                "Amount": 4,
                "Type": 334,
                "Slot": 4
            },
            {
                "Data": 7,
                "Durability": 7,
                "Amount": 1,
                "Type": 35,
                "Slot": 5
            },
            {
                "Data": 44,
                "Durability": 16428,
                "Amount": 1,
                "Type": 373,
                "Slot": 6
            },
            {
                "Durability": 0,
                "Amount": 1,
                "Type": 44,
                "Slot": 7
            },
            {
                "Data": 7,
                "Durability": 7,
                "Amount": 1,
                "Type": 44,
                "Slot": 8
            },
            {
                "Durability": 0,
                "Amount": 2,
                "Type": 369,
                "Slot": 9
            }
        ],
        "Exhaustion": 2.9359312057495117,
        "Name": "runelynx",
        "CurrentItemID": 334,
        "GameMode": "CREATIVE",
        "IsOP": true
    },
    "ServerStatus": {
        "MaxMemory": 1413021696,
        "AvailableMemory": 121421064,
        "OnlinePlayers": [
            {
                "Name": "runelynx",
                "IP": "/81.31.95.254:63218"
            },
            {
                "Name": "BenBestvater",
                "IP": "/192.0.155.77:53885"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ServerSettings": {
        "NetherEnabled": true,
        "Name": "Runic Paradise",
        "Port": 25565,
        "Build": "git-Bukkit-1.6.4-R2.0-22-g40a262b-b2940jnks (MC: 1.7.2)",
        "MaxPlayers": 35,
        "FlyingEnabled": false,
        "OnlineMode": true,
        "DefaultGameMode": "SURVIVAL"
    }
}
```

////EDIT////

Note this PHP script is being called by my game server so  I can't see any results displayed via HTML; instead Im writing to my DB to try and see the results... and after using all the examples below, the end result in the DB is just a blank cell. Such as the example below:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST["jsonData"]);
foreach ($json->ServerStatus->OnlinePlayers as $player){
    $pname .= $player->Name;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$mysqli = new mysqli("asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO log (Notes)
VALUES ('". $pname ."')");
```

Comment: the json php extension is installed? json_decode is correct.

Comment: once you decode json in php, it's a php data structure. You'd access like you would any OTHER php data structure.

Comment: thanks. Now its completely unreadable above thanks to the edit someone just made :(

Comment: @skrilled The JSON extension has been built into PHP since 5.2.0.

Comment: Assuming things is not how you solve problems. I answered a question a few weeks ago in which someone had to install the php5-json package to resolve their problem. Thanks though :D

Comment: var_dump($json) returns nothing

Comment: Json is now readable, use a validator like http://jsonlint.com/ to cleanup format. :)

Comment: I found a help article from my host that says json needs to be enabled... I just dont have access to do it... calling them up.  http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7853/working-with-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have your OnlinePlayers as an attribute for ServerStatus so you can have it like this:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST["jsonData"]);
foreach ($json->ServerStatus->OnlinePlayers as $player){
    var_dump($player);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

check the [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/skq-afm)

**Update:**
another [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qur-a6f) that echos the Name of the player.

Comment: Pls see the edit at the bottom of the question now? I can see the fiddle works but for some reason I'm getting nothing back.

Comment: @runelynx - check the second fiddle, the Name being echoed correctly.
you need to make sure that DB params are all ok.

Comment: my host confirmed JSON is off by default,I need to manually activate it... doing that and trying this all again..........

Comment: @runelynx - then you have your answer :)

Comment: still nada... I changed this php.ini file they have in my account but the behavior is still the same - using identical code to the fiddle, I get an empty $json... its like the decode doesnt do anything.  Im thinking maybe the server needs to reload the ini or restart or something, calling them back ;)

Comment: @runelynx - after ini changing you need to restart apache for sure.

Comment: my phpinfo says JSON is enabled, but still no results :(
www.runic-paradise.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: try `$json = substr($json, 3);` then decode it. check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call) for informaiton

Comment: still no dice :( dug further into that thread though, I see someone mentions magic quotes...  in my phpinfo it says: magic_quotes_gpc=ON ...   seeing if I can do something with that

Comment: @runelynx = you can close this thread and open new one for json_decode failure

Comment: ohmygod!! IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  $d = stripslashes($_POST['param']);
}else{
  $d = $_POST['param'];
}
Solved my problem!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

PHP's magic quoting might be interfering with the post data, try this (and do check $json for null, it's the only way `json_decode` will tell you anything went wrong):

```
$json = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonData']));
if ($json === NULL) {
  error_log("json could not be decoded: " . json_last_error_msg());
}
```

More at the [PHP runtime config](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc).

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST["jsonData"]);
$onlinePlayers = $json->ServerStatus->OnlinePlayers;

foreach ($onlinePlayers as $player){
    print_r($player);
}
```