# json_decode returns null on facebook graph object sent from android to php

Tags: php, android, facebook-graph-api, json

Gives null on using json_decode on facebook graph object sent from android to php.

```
$json =  file_get_contents('php://input');


$data = json_decode($json);


var_dump($data);
```

returns NULL
when search i found this [json_decode returns NULL after webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call)

used same code with all possibilities

```
$json =  file_get_contents('php://input');
     $json = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $json);
    $json = trim(substr($json ,3)); 


    $data = json_decode($json);


    var_dump($data);
```

tried this also ,returns null

Comment: Check whether your `JSON` is valid on jslint.com

Comment: we are sending facebook graph object received at android to php server with some concatenation to that fb graph object. some times it is decoding fine. but some time it gives a null when decoded using json_decode, but when i echo $json =  file_get_contents('php://input'); we are getting the json every time. may problem with json_decode

Comment: Solved i was getting a value with special characters. json_decode was not able to decode the json, so it was returning null ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced the same problem. It is due to special characters in the String. Handle the special characters to avoid null value.