# json_decode not working after cURL call

Tags: php, curl, get, json

I send a `GET` request to a server using curl and get back json data. When I print this data in the browser I can see the proper json structure without slashes(magic quotes turned off)-no problem at all.
Even when I copy paste this json data from the browser to another php file in a variable and then try to decode it it works fine. The data is decoded in that file.
However after getting the data from the cURL request when I try to decode the data it fails. All it returns is: Array

Here is what I'm trying:

```
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$d=json_decode($resp,true);
```

I don't know why this weird behaviour??
I have tried almost everything mentioned in this thread [json_decode returns NULL after webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call)

I've also detected the encoding of the string returned by cURL call using `mb_detect_encoding` and it is UTF-8

This thing is driving me crazy...

**Update:**  OK.....it seems json_decode has infact decoded the data and returned in $d variable but I'm not able to access the element from the array. I used **print_r** to see the structure of the array. It is somewhat lik this:

```
Array ( 
    [response] => Array ( 
                    [start] => 0 
                    [docs] => Array ( 
                              [0] => Array ( 
                                       [id] => S132250037010452  
                                       [slno] => 452 
                                     ) 
                            )
                    [numFound] => 1 
                  ) 
)
```

When I try to access the element id using:

```
echo $d[response][docs][0][id];
```

I get a notice stating: Use of undefined constant response - assumed 'response' on that line. What does this mean??

Comment: What did you set for your `curl_setopt`? If you `var_dump($resp)` what does it show?

Comment: ok some progress.....I'm able to see the structure of the array using print_r, which means the json is decoded,  but still not able to access the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit, to access this field you need to enclose between `'`

```
echo $d['response']['docs'][0]['id']; // <--- Will return 'S132250037010452'
```

If you don't enclose the names, PHP will try to use as constants

Comment: still the same result. this time error also has the quote. Use of undefined constant response - assumed 'response'

Comment: It's not possible to get the same result.... if you use `'` or `"` PHP doesn't try to use as constants. Are you sure you write exactly as i wrote? (or with `"` instead of `'`)

Comment: double quotes finally worked for me......thanks man you made my day....:)