# cant decode json array to php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having troubles with decoding json array.
I have an external url in json format: http://genie.kz/api.json

And i am trying to get with function `file_fet_contents` then decode it.

Here is the code:

```
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'http://genie.kz/api.json' ), true );

foreach($data as $item) {
    echo $item['code'];
}
```

However, i could not get any values and `var_dump()` retrives `NULL`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/689364/4503462

Comment: in your json data have a special character so u dont find data array.so u can json_decode with special character's function.